# Implement mapster dependency injection via Simple Injector IoC container

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector, mapster

I'm using Mapster for mapping and Simple Injector in my .net framework 4.8 MVC and WebApi controllers.
I'd like to inject Mapster as a dependency in my services but I can't figure it out how to make it work with Simple Injector. The Mapster documentation is really vague in my opinion:

[Mapster - Dependency Injection](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Dependency-Injection)

[Mapster - References](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki)

Can someone provide and example of how to use Mapster with Simple Injector? Doesn't matter if the controller is mvc or a web api.

The code I need is the configuration in Application_Start in Global.asax.cs and in the service concrete. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with Mapster, but after looking at the documentation link you provided, I'm assuming that integrating with Simple Injector can be done as follows:

```cs
var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();
container.RegisterInstance(config);
services.RegisterSingleton<IMapper, SimpleInjectorMapper>();
```

Where `SimpleInjectorMapper` is:

```cs
public sealed class SimpleInjectorMapper : ServiceMapper
{
    public SimpleInjectorMapper(
        Container container, TypeAdapterConfig config)
        : base(container, config)
    {
    }
}
```

The 'trick' here is that the Simple Injector `Container` class implements `System.IServiceProvider`, which is the base interface used by most of the DI facilities in .NET and .NET Core and is the base interface that the MS.DI abstraction relies on. Mapsters `ServiceMapper` expects an `IServiceProvider` in its constructor, which is now provided using the `Container`.

There are a few downsides to this approach. Main downside is that in case a dependency is missing, you'll get a more generic "no service registered" exception in line with what MS.DI would throw, instead of a very information rich exception that Simple Injector would throw in case the resolve would fail when you call `Container.GetInstance`.

This, however, is a as far as I can go in providing an answer. If you wish to integrate more deeply with Simple Injector, you likely need a more complex `SimpleInjectorMapper` implementation, but others (e.g. the designers behind Mapster) need to help you with that. At least, hopefully, this answer will get you started.